# How to copy a local branch to a new one?

Tags: git

I have a local branch (bug123) that I want to clone/copy (bug456), how can I do that without branching from bug123 branch?  I eventually want to rebase branch bug456 and merge with master.

$ git checkout -b bug456 bug123   //Does this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "clone/copy" a branch? A branch in git is just a pointer to a changeset. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/

Comment: so, this works? $ git checkout -b bug456 bug123

Comment: it will create another reference to the same changeset `bug123` is currently pointing on. Not sure if it's what you want though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to clone/copy ... without branching from bug123

That makes no sense. "Cloning" a branch and "branching" from a branch are the same thing; you just make a new branch using bug123 as its starting point:

```
$ git branch bug456 bug123
```

Comment: cool...thanks wasn't sure if it mattered where I branched (from master or the bug branch)